# In polars, can I create a categorical type with levels myself?

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

In Pandas, I can specify the levels of a Categorical type myself:

```py
MyCat = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['A','B','C'], ordered=True)
my_data = pd.Series(['A','A','B'], dtype=MyCat)
```

This means that

1. I can make sure that different columns and sets use the same dtype
2. I can specify an ordering for the levels.

Is there a way to do this with Polars? I know you can use the string cache feature to achieve 1) in a different way, however I'm interested if my dtype/levels can be specified directly. I'm not aware of any way to achieve 2), however I think the categorical dtypes in Arrow do allow an optional ordering, so maybe it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Polars `0.20.0` a new `pl.Enum` type has been added for this purpose.

> When the categories are known up front use `Enum`.

- https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/concepts/data-types/categoricals/#enum-vs-categorical

```py
my_enum = pl.Enum(['A', 'B', 'C'])
my_data = pl.Series(['A', 'A', 'B'], dtype=my_enum)
```

```py
# shape: (3,)
# Series: '' [enum]
# [
#     "A"
#     "A"
#     "B"
# ]
```

```py
my_data.to_physical()
```

```py
# shape: (3,)
# Series: '' [u32]
# [
#     0
#     0
#     1
# ]
```

Answer (score 11):

### EDIT 2024-02-29:

This answer is outdated. You should use Polars `Enum` type for this.

### Old answer

Not directly, but we can influence how the global string cache is filled. The global string cache simply increments a counter for every new category added.

So if we start with an empty cache and we do a pre-fill in the order that we think is important, the later categories use the cached integer.

Here is an example:

```py
import string
import polars as pl

with pl.StringCache():
    # the first run will fill the global string cache counting from 0..25
    # for all 26 letters in the alphabet
    pl.Series(list(string.ascii_uppercase)).cast(pl.Categorical)
    
    # now the global string cache is populated with all categories
    # we cast the string columns
    df = (
        pl.DataFrame({
            "letters": ["A", "B", "D"],
            "more_letters": ["Z", "B", "J"]
        })
        .with_columns(pl.col(pl.Utf8).cast(pl.Categorical))
        .with_columns(pl.col(pl.Categorical).to_physical().suffix("_real_category"))
    )

print(df)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────────┬──────────────┬───────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ letters ┆ more_letters ┆ letters_real_category ┆ more_letters_real_category │
│ ---     ┆ ---          ┆ ---                   ┆ ---                        │
│ cat     ┆ cat          ┆ u32                   ┆ u32                        │
╞═════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════════════╪════════════════════════════╡
│ A       ┆ Z            ┆ 0                     ┆ 25                         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B       ┆ B            ┆ 1                     ┆ 1                          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ D       ┆ J            ┆ 3                     ┆ 9                          │
└─────────┴──────────────┴───────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘
```