# How to create non-alphabetically ordered Categorical column in Polars Dataframe?

Tags: data-science, categorical-data, python-polars

In Pandas, you can create an "ordered" Categorical column from existing string column as follows:

```py
column_values_with_custom_order = ["B", "A", "C"]

df["Column"] = pd.Categorical(df.Column, categories=column_values_with_custom_order, ordered=True)
```

In Polars documentation, I couldn't find such way to create ordered columns. However, I could reproduce this by using `pl.from_pandas(df)` so I suspect that this is possible with Polars as well.

What would be the recommended way to this?

I tried to create new column with:

```py
polars_df.with_columns(col("Column").cast(pl.Categorical))
```

but I don't know how to include the custom ordering to this.

I also checked [In polars, can I create a categorical type with levels myself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70934789/in-polars-can-i-create-a-categorical-type-with-levels-myself), but I would prefer not to add another column to my Dataframe only for ordering.

Comment: Note that in the linked answer, another column is not added to the DataFrame … merely that a small Series is created with the desired ordering while the StringCache is in effect.  The purpose of that initial Series is to set the order of the strings and nothing more.  It can even be discarded, and never added to any DataFrame.  Then, as long as the same StringCache remains in effect, any subsequent Categorical columns in any DatFrame will respect the order from that initial Series, even if the Series was discarded.

Comment: I notice it now that the linked answer, in fact, contains the solution to my question. Thanks for noting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
     {"cats": ["z", "z", "k", "a", "b"], "vals": [3, 1, 2, 2, 3]}
     )
```

and you want to make cats a categorical but you want the categorical ordered as

```
myorder=["k", "z", "b", "a"]
```

There are two ways to do this.  One way is with `pl.StringCache()` as in the question you reference and the other is more messy.  The former does not require you add any columns to your df.  It's actually very succinct.

```
with pl.StringCache():
    pl.Series(myorder).cast(pl.Categorical)
    df=df.with_columns(pl.col('cats').cast(pl.Categorical))
```

What happens is that everything in the StringCache gets the same key values so when the `myorder` list is casted that saves what keys get allocated to each string value.  When your df gets casted under the same cache it gets the same key/string values which are in the order you wanted.

The other way to do this is as follows:

You have to sort your df by the ordering then you can do `set_ordering('physical')`.  If you want to maintain your original order then you just have to use `with_row_count` at the beginning so you can restore that order.

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
df=df.with_row_count('i').join(
        pl.from_dicts([{'order':x, 'cats':y} for x,y in enumerate(myorder)]), on='cats') \
    .sort('order').drop('order') \
    .with_columns(pl.col('cats').cast(pl.Categorical).cat.set_ordering('physical')) \
    .sort('i').drop('i')
```

You can verify by doing:

```
df.select(['cats',pl.col('cats').to_physical().alias('phys')])

shape: (5, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ cats ┆ phys │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ cat  ┆ u32  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ z    ┆ 1    │
│ z    ┆ 1    │
│ k    ┆ 0    │
│ a    ┆ 3    │
│ b    ┆ 2    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! This answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

From the doc:
Use:

```
polars_df.with_columns(col("Column").cast(pl.categorical).cat.set_ordering("lexical"))
```

See the [doc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cat.set_ordering.html)

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"cats": ["z", "z", "k", "a", "b"], "vals": [3, 1, 2, 2, 3]}
).with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("cats").cast(pl.Categorical).cat.set_ordering("lexical"),
    ]
)
df.sort(["cats", "vals"])
```

Comment: I believe this is just ordering by alphabetical order? What if I wanted to define the order as ["k", "z", "b", "a"]. I don't think this would work then.

Result from the code:
shape: (5, 2)
cats  vals
cat  i64
"a"  2
"b"  3
"k"  2
"z"  1
"z"  3

Comment: I guess you can do `set_ordering("physical")` but the categories have to appear in the order you want them to be.

Answer (score 1):

The [`pl.Enum`](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/concepts/data-types/categoricals/#enum-vs-categorical) type was added in Polars `0.20.0` to deal with cases of this kind.

```py
my_order = ["k", "z", "b", "a"]

df.with_columns(pl.col("cats").cast(pl.Enum(my_order)))
```

```py
shape: (5, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ cats ┆ vals │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ enum ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ z    ┆ 3    │
│ z    ┆ 1    │
│ k    ┆ 2    │
│ a    ┆ 2    │
│ b    ┆ 3    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Check/verify the order:

```py
(df.with_columns(pl.col("cats").cast(pl.Enum(my_order)))
   .sort("cats")
   .with_columns(order = pl.col("cats").to_physical())
)
```

```py
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ cats ┆ vals ┆ order │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ enum ┆ i64  ┆ u32   │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ k    ┆ 2    ┆ 0     │
│ z    ┆ 3    ┆ 1     │
│ z    ┆ 1    ┆ 1     │
│ b    ┆ 3    ┆ 2     │
│ a    ┆ 2    ┆ 3     │
└──────┴──────┴───────┘
```