# Make a categorical column which has categories ['a', 'b', 'c'] in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

How do I make a Categorical column which has:

- elements: `['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']`
- categories `['a', 'b', 'c']`

in polars?

In pandas, I would do:

```py
In [31]: pd.Series(pd.Categorical(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a'], categories=['a', 'b', 'c']))
Out[31]:
0    a
1    b
2    a
3    a
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I have no idea how to do this in polars, the docs for `Categorical` look completely empty:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Categorical.html

Comment: Not sure either but I did find https://stackoverflow.com/a/70957256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `StringCache`

```
with pl.StringCache():
    pl.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=pl.Categorical())
    s = pl.Series(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a','z'], dtype=pl.Categorical())
```

Everything in the `StringCache` context will share the same index/value mapping so the first line initialized the mapping with the categories you want. The second line is the Series you want to keep. I added an extra 'z' so that we can see:

```
s.to_physical()
shape: (5,)
Series: '' [u32]
[
    0
    1
    0
    0
    3
]
```

Note that the `s` series skips 2 as it doesn't have a c value in it.

Answer (score 2):

The [`pl.Enum`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/docs/python/dev/reference/api/polars.Enum.html#polars.Enum) type has been added in [Polars 0.20.0](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.20.0)

```py
s = pl.Series(["a", "b", "a", "a"], dtype=pl.Enum(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

```py
>>> s.cat.get_categories()
shape: (3,)
Series: '' [str]
[
    "a"
    "b"
    "c"
]
```

```py
>>> s.to_physical()
shape: (4,)
Series: '' [u32]
[
    0 
    1
    0
    0
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When I dig to parameters in Series, I found dtype parameter and I found a link in documentation, there is a Categorical in Other section.

[DataTypes](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/datatypes.html)

is this what you need?:

```
elements = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']
categories = ['a', 'b', 'c']
categorical_col = pl.Series(elements, dtype=pl.Categorical(categories))
```

Comment: Nope, sorry. Try putting random nonsense in `categories`, there's no validation here