# polars - get "levels" of categorical column?

Tags: python, python-polars

In pandas if we create a categorical and then drop one of the values, we can still see that value from the internal dictionary.

```py
In [44]: s = pd.Series(['one', 'two', 'three']).astype('category')[:2]

In [45]: s
Out[45]:
0    one
1    two
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['one', 'three', 'two']

In [46]: s.value_counts()
Out[46]:
one      1
two      1
three    0
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

`.value_counts` shows that category `three` has `0` occurrences, even though `three` doesn't appear in `s`. It knows it's part of the levels of that category.
You can get all the categories with:

```py
In [52]: s.dtype.categories
Out[52]: Index(['one', 'three', 'two'], dtype='object')
```

In polars, can we recover values from the internal dictionary if they've been dropped from the data?

```py
In [47]: s = pl.Series('category', ['one', 'two', 'three'], pl.Categorical)[:2]

In [48]: s
Out[48]:
shape: (2,)
Series: 'category' [cat]
[
        "one"
        "two"
]

In [49]: s.value_counts()
Out[49]:
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────┬────────┐
│ category ┆ counts │
│ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ cat      ┆ u32    │
╞══════════╪════════╡
│ two      ┆ 1      │
│ one      ┆ 1      │
└──────────┴────────┘
```

Is it even possible to get all the categories from the dtype?

---

Note: this is not the same as [Make a categorical column which has categories ['a', 'b', 'c'] in Polars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76613542/make-a-categorical-column-which-has-categories-a-b-c-in-polars). Here, I have already made the categorical data, and want to see which categories it has

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a categorical column which has categories \['a', 'b', 'c'\] in Polars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76613542/make-a-categorical-column-which-has-categories-a-b-c-in-polars)

Comment: no. I've already made the categorical, and now I want to see which categories it has

Comment: As of date, from Polars GitHub issues i.e., [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6003) and [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5671) (your requirements) are in open status (not yet implemented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.cat.get_categories()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cat.get_categories.html#polars.Expr.cat.get_categories) has since been added to Polars.

```py
s = pl.Series('category', ['one', 'two', 'three'], pl.Categorical)[:2]
```

```py
s.cat.get_categories()
```

```py
# shape: (3,)
# Series: 'category' [str]
# [
#     "one"
#     "two"
#     "three"
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through pyarrow.

```
s = pl.Series('category', ['one', 'two', 'one','three', 'four','five'], pl.Categorical)
s[0,1,2,4,5]
shape: (5,)
Series: 'category' [cat]
[
    "one"
    "two"
    "one"
    "four"
    "five"
]

s[0,1,2,4,5].to_arrow().dictionary
<pyarrow.lib.LargeStringArray object at 0x7f6c098197e0>
[
"one",
"two",
"three",
"four",
"five"
]
```

It looks like when you convert to arrow that the physical int is reset though. Here's an example.

```
with pl.StringCache():
    df=pl.DataFrame({
        'a':['apple','banana'],
        'b':['carrot','apple'],
    }, schema={'a':pl.Categorical(), 'b':pl.Categorical(),})
df.with_columns(pl.all().to_physical().suffix('_id'))
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────────┬────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a       ┆ b      ┆ a_id ┆ b_id │
│ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ cat     ┆ cat    ┆ u32  ┆ u32  │
╞═════════╪════════╪══════╪══════╡
│ apple   ┆ carrot ┆ 0    ┆ 2    │
│ banana  ┆ apple  ┆ 1    ┆ 0    │
└─────────┴────────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Because of StringCache, apple is 0 in both cases, at least to polars. However...

```
df['a'].to_arrow()
<pyarrow.lib.DictionaryArray object at 0x7f6c09653840>

-- dictionary:
[
    "apple",
    "banana"
]
-- indices:
[
    0,
    1
]

df['b'].to_arrow()
<pyarrow.lib.DictionaryArray object at 0x7f6c09653c30>

-- dictionary:
[
    "carrot",
    "apple"
]
-- indices:
[
    0,
    1
]
```