# Save Polars' categorical mapping

Tags: python-polars

I have a Polars dataframe with categorical columns, e.g.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'foo': ['a', 'b']}, schema={'foo': pl.Categorical})
```

For modelling purposes I need to map the categorical values to integers:

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col(pl.Categorical).to_physical().name.suffix('_cat'))
```

Here `a` is 0 and `b` is 1. This works as intended, but it depends on the order of the rows. If I switch `a` and `b` in `df` then `a` is 1 and `b` is 0.

I don't care about the mapped values per se, but if I get a new dataframe to use with my model I need to apply the same mapping.
I can extract the mapping myself into a dict and later run `map_dict`, but is there a smarter way?

Comment: If you turn the string cache on before you create even the first df then open the second df it will automatically have consistent categorical mappings. That said I would explicitly save the id mappings if they're embedded in a model.

Answer (score 0):

As Dean MacGregor pointed out, you need to use the global `StringCache`:

```py
with pl.StringCache():
    df1 = pl.DataFrame({'foo': ['a', 'b']}, schema={'foo': pl.Categorical})
    df2 = pl.DataFrame({'foo': ['b', 'a']}, schema={'foo': pl.Categorical})
    
    print(df1.with_columns(pl.col(pl.Categorical).to_physical().name.suffix('_cat')))
    print(df2.with_columns(pl.col(pl.Categorical).to_physical().name.suffix('_cat')))
```

Output:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────────┐
│ foo ┆ foo_cat │
│ --- ┆ ---     │
│ cat ┆ u32     │
╞═════╪═════════╡
│ a   ┆ 0       │
│ b   ┆ 1       │
└─────┴─────────┘
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────────┐
│ foo ┆ foo_cat │
│ --- ┆ ---     │
│ cat ┆ u32     │
╞═════╪═════════╡
│ b   ┆ 1       │
│ a   ┆ 0       │
└─────┴─────────┘
```

Unfortunately currently Polars doesn't expose any way to provide a mapping yourself or extract the contents of the string cache (unless you know all strings used as categories).
Also, if you need to use the same mapping across multiple processes/invocations I think you're out of luck.

Reference:

- [In polars, can I create a categorical type with levels myself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70934789/in-polars-can-i-create-a-categorical-type-with-levels-myself)
- [`enable_string_cache`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.enable_string_cache.html#polars.enable_string_cache)
- [`StringCache`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.StringCache.html#polars.StringCache)

Comment: There is a new [`pl.Enum`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/concepts/data-types/categoricals/#enum-vs-categorical) type for providing mappings.